# jquery address in combination with "regular" anchor points

Tags: anchor, jquery-address

On this site we've implemented Jquery Address to remember and load ajax content correctly
when using back/forward buttons in the browser.

The problem have arisen with links that has regular anchor points, that is:

```
<a href="product.php?prodid=5" name="product5" />a product link</a>
```

the purpose of this is of course to make brwoser scroll down to same position
you were before clicking the link and clicking back (this is a product listing page for the record).

Is there a way to exclude (or not include) certain links that jquery adress catches?

Comment: Post how you use jQuery Address (the line where you call it).

Comment: @Blender
$.address.change(function(event) {
 switch(event.pathNames[0])
{
case 'brand': {
   
$('#center_column').empty();
$('#center_column').load('products.php?' + event.queryString);
break;

Answer (score 1):

You could just exclude all of the links with a `name` attribute:

```
// Use this selector when initializing jQuery Address.
$('a:not([name])').address()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Blender. My real problem was never this. I was mixing things up. Since I loaded data dynamically when pressed back scrollTop was reset. Now I save scrollTop before load and then set it back.